# Creating a user without a password

Tags: ubuntu, users, git, non-root-user

I'm trying to create a user without password like this:

```
sudo adduser \
   --system \
   --shell /bin/bash \
   --gecos ‘User for managing of git version control’ \
   --group \
   --disabled-password \
   --home /home/git \
   git
```

It's created fine. But when I try to login under the git user I'm getting the password entering:

```
su git
Password:...
```

When I leave it empty I get an error:

```
su: Authentication failed
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, the authentication failed as expected. You won't get a "there is no password, you can't login" error message.

Comment: But I need to create .ssh folder under the git user, how should I do that?

Comment: Either create it as root and set the correct permissions, or execute `su git` as root where you don't have to provide a password.

Comment: How should I set the correct permissions?

Comment: By using `chmod` and `chown`.

Comment: Please can you wtite the command that I have to exec?

Comment: @Erik Can you provide output of `sudo grep git /etc/shadow`?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that letting the git user have Bash as a shell is a bad idea, security wise. That would allow users of this repo to get a shell in your server.

If you set the shell to /usr/bin/git-shell you can limit their account to using git and nothing else. (You should also limit SFTP access but that can only be done from /etc/sshd_config).

Now, once you changed the shell, "su" won't work as-is. You'll have to do "su -s /bin/sh git" instead.

Comment: Besides the recommendation of not using an interactive shell, also note that _system_ accounts home prefix is usually not `/home`, but `/var/lib`, `/etc` or similar (or even no home). They are meant for automated services, not actual (human) users. Why bother with `--system` if you're changing all defaults to the values meant for human  users?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You've created a user with a “disabled password”, meaning that there is no password that will let you log in as this user. This is different from creating a user that anyone can log in as without supplying a password, which is achieved by specifying an empty password and is very rarely useful.

In order to execute commands as such “system” users who don't log in normally, you need to hop via the root account:

```
su -c 'su git -c "git init"'
```

or

```
sudo -u git git init
```

If you want certain users to be able to run commands as the `git` user without letting them run commands as root, set up sudo (run `visudo` as root and add a line like `%gitters ALL = (git) ALL`).

Comment: Another one: `sudo su - git git init`

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 seems like does not have `--disabled-password` parameter, could there be any alternative solution

Comment: @alper This has nothing to do with my answer. But anyway, yes, it does.

Comment: When I do `sudo su git -c "cat main.py"` it can read the files where `sudo` operation is perform. Is it possible to prevent that forcing switched user to run the command in its home directory rather than main user's directory?

Comment: @alper Write the full path: `sudo -u git cat /wherever/main.py`. Or add a `cd` command: `sudo -u git sh -c 'cd /wherever && cat main.py'`. If you want to be sure that the other user doesn't get access to the current directory even if the command doesn't do what was intended, change directories **outside**: `(cd /wherever && sudo -u git cat main.py)`

Comment: It does not allow me to do `cd` I am not sure why `sudo: cd: command not found`. But I am able to do other solutions

Comment: @alper You didn't use the commands I posted. You used one of many variants (too many for me to guess the exact one) that would result in this particular error. You need to invoke a shell for `cd` and `&&`.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' // Ah I forget to use `sh`, now it works

Answer (score 92):

The `--disabled-password` option will not set a password, meaning no password is legal, but  login  is still possible (for example with SSH RSA keys).

To create an user without a password, use `passwd -d $username` after the user is created to make the password empty. Note not all systems allow users with empty password to log in.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in version 16 ubuntu

Comment: @DanielTate got it kind of working with: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472968/32558

Answer (score 12):

If you want to access the system under the git user you should use sudo:

```
sudo -s -u git
```

or

```
sudo su - git
```

Answer (score 10):

**Create an user with empty password**

```
sudo useradd test-user-0
echo test-user-0:U6aMy0wojraho | sudo chpasswd -e
su test-user-0
```

The password prompt still shows unfortunately.

But if you just hit enter without typing anything, and it logins as the user `test-user-0`.

The `-e` flags tells `chpasswd` that the password is already encrypted, and `U6aMy0wojraho` is the hash of the empty string.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Terminal autologin with `getty -a`**

On the terminal at least, you don't need to create an user without a password to allow someone to not type their passwords every time.

I was able to do this on BusyBox by modifying `inittab`: [How to login automatically without typing the root username or password in Buildroot BusyBox init?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299408/how-to-login-automatically-without-typing-the-root-username-or-password-in-build)

So I believe that it should not be very hard to adapt that technique by modifying Ubuntu 18.04's systemd init system scripts to setup a `getty -a <user>` terminal as mentioned in that answer, although I haven't tried to do it myself.

Answer (score 10):

I think this is what you want:

```
adduser --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash --gecos "User" $username
```

You'll be able to

```
su $username
```

to run commands as that user, in `/bin/bash` or whatever shell you specify. `--gecos "User"` just put `"User"` into the comment field so you aren't prompted for that information. You can put whatever you want into that field.

Comment: Note that adduser from shadow-utils 4.1.5.1 does not have the option `--disabled-password`

Answer (score 0):

Once you created a user with this command-line option `--disabled-password` follow below instructions as root user

```
sudo visudo
```

Add below line at EOF.

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Save visudo file. Now try to execute sudo commands with newly created user. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

For some versions of adduser there is a -p option for supplying the encrypted password, however if an empty string is supplied it is the same has setting no password:
`adduser -p '' mypasswordlessuser`

Comment: Which versions are those? The latest debian version (3.134) doesn't have that flag https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/adduser/adduser.8.en.html