# useradd create a user without password and accessible only by ssh

Tags: linux, useradd

I'm writing a script that automatically creates a user using the `useradd` command (I need this one and not `adduser`).

I want to create it in a way that it is accessible only using ssh (the script already adds the public_key among authorized keys).

```
useradd --system --shell /bin/bash $NEW_USER
```

Does this command allow login by password? If yes, how can I disable it?

The objective I want to achieve is something like `--disable-password` of `useradd` described in this post: [Creating a user without a password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56765/creating-a-user-without-a-password).

Comment: Do you set a password for the user? If not, the user has no password and will not be able to log in with a password.

Comment: @they Perfect, that partially answers my question. However, in scripts, it's normal that I don't get prompted to insert the password? Why does this happen?

Comment: Adding to @they's comment, the useradd man page says: `-p, --password PASSWORD     The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.`    i.e. if you don't set a password, it will be disabled.    BTW, if you want to be sure, or if you need to disable the password for an existing account, you can run `passwd -l username` to lock the account (i.e. disable the password).

Comment: I missed the last part when reading from `man useradd`. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @cas You should make that an answer.

Comment: If you guys want to write the answer I will validate it to repay your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useradd` creates an account with a disabled password by default if you don't give it one with the `-p` option.

From `man useradd`:

> `-p`, `--password` PASSWORD
>
> The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.

BTW, if you need to disable the password for an existing account, you can run `passwd -l username` to lock the account (i.e. disable the password).  From `man passwd`:

> `-l`, `--lock`
>
> Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a password by
> changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted value (it adds a
> `!` at the beginning of the password).
>
> **Note that this does not disable the account**. The user may still be able to
> login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key). To disable the
> account, administrators should use `usermod --expiredate 1` (this set the
> account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).
>
> Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their password.

The fact that it just invalidates the password rather than deleting it allows it to be unlocked later with `passwd -u`, without the systems administrator needing to know what the original password was or setting it to some "default" password (possibly insecure, possibly well-known):

> `-u`, `--unlock`
>
> Unlock the password of the named account. This option re-enables
> a password by changing the password back to its previous value
> (to the value before using the `-l` option).

i.e. it removes the `!` added to the beginning of the crypted password by the `-l` option.